# check if a number is hex in shell script without specifying number of characters limit [ bash ]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to check if a number is hex in shell script. I have tried the below code where it checks against the range `0-9A-Fa-f`.

i.e, if HEX="301D" [ 4 characters ], then the below code will work. My objective is to remove the dependency on number of characters in the check.

```
 #!/bin/bash

    HEX="301DE8"

    #if ! [[ $HEX =~ ^[[:xdigit:]]{10}$ ]] ; then
    #if ! [[ $HEX =~ ^[0-9A-Fa-f]{10}$ ]] ; then
    #if ! [[ $HEX =~ ^[0-9A-Fa-f]$ ]] ; then
    if ! [[ $HEX =~ ^[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}$ ]] ; then
        echo "string is not hex"
    else
        echo "string contains hex digits"
    fi
```

I have tried by increasing the limit and removing the limit. But both didn't work. I am thinking of using a while loop to check against each characters as a last option. 
Is there a better method to implement the check without specifying the no. of characters ?

Comment: Do you want to check if a string contains only hex digits, no matter how many? Are you looking for the regex `^[[:xdigit:]]+$` (one or more of `[[:xdigit:]]`)?

Comment: @Benjamin W, Yes. But I tried the below option and it stil didnt work. if ! [[ $HEX =~ ^[[0-9A-Fa-f]]+$ ]] ; then

Comment: It's either `[0-9A-Fa-f]` or `[[:xdigit:]]` (notice number of `[ ]`).

Comment: @benjamin W, Sorry. My mistake. [[ $HEX =~ ^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$ ]] works fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: `[[:xdigit:]]` is the safer choice, by the way, as not every locale has A-F expand to ABCDEF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't do it with regex.

```
HEX="301DE8"
(( 16#$HEX ))
```

then you check the return code of the last statement by `$?`.

If it is `0`, your HEX is ok, otherwise, it is not HEX number.

Comment: This incorrectly says that `HEX='F+!P4_'` is hex, it incorrectly says that `HEX=0` is not, and it allows arbitrary code execution with `HEX='1-a[$(ls>&2)]'`

Comment: @thatotherguy double quote it?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify that the string is at least 1 character long using `{1,}`:

```
HEX="301DE8"

if ! [[ $HEX =~ ^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,}$ ]] ; then
    echo "string is not hex"
else
    echo "string contains hex digits"
fi
```

This will match any string that consists of at least 1 of the specified characters (`0-9A-Fa-f`)

edit: Although Kent's solution here is much more elegant :)